# Why is my input element not emitting the event?

Tags: angular, parent-child, eventemitter

I have an input field which chooses a colour. The colour, 'selectedColor' should emit up to the parent, but even logging out in the child doesn't render anything. I have stripped back the colour picker and that doesn't seem to change anything either.

**.parent**

```
<app-settings-color-item (newColor)="getColorValue($event)" [setting]="config.background_color"></app-settings-color-item>
```

**parent-component.ts**

```
public getColorValue(selectedColor: Colors) {
  if (selectedColor) {
    this.selectedColor = selectedColor;
  }
}
```

**.child**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="setting">
    <li>
        <input 
        [value]="setting.data.hex_code" 
        [cpPosition]="'center'"
        [ngModel]="selectedColor" 
        [style.background]="setting.data.hex_code"
        [(colorPicker)]="setting.data.hex_code" 
        [cpOKButton]="true"
        (colorPickerChange)="selectedColor" 
        [cpOKButton]="true" 
        [cpSaveClickOutside]="false"
        [cpOKButtonClass]="'update'"
        (change)="selectColor(selectedColor)">
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

**.child-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Config } from 'src/app/config';
import { Colors } from '../colors';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings-color-item',
  templateUrl: './settings-color-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../settings.component.scss','./settings-color-item.component.scss']
})
export class SettingsColorItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  setting: Config;

  @Output()
  private newColor = new EventEmitter<Colors>();

  selectedColor: Colors;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public selectColor(){
    if(this.selectedColor){
      const selectedColor = this.selectedColor;
      this.newColor.emit(selectedColor);
      console.log(selectedColor);//doesn't log anything? :/
    }
  }

}
```

I've been working on child event emitters all day today and the only difference is that this is an input element rather than a select dropdown. The set up is the same in the other components and works, but this doesn't.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this isn't working?

Comment: Perhaps `(colorPickerChange)="selectedColor"` should be `(colorPickerChange)="selectColor()" `?

Comment: `(colorPickerChange)="selectedColor"` - don't know what you're using here, but maybe this overrides the `(change)` event. Also, you should log something before `if(this.selectedColor)` to verify if `this.selectedColor` has some value

Comment: Yeah, so I stripped this back and just checked to see if anything got passed up and removing the color picker options, does nothing...I'll check R.Richards suggestion quickly.

Comment: no, doesn't emit still

Comment: See my updated comment (refresh this page if you do not see it).

Comment: not sure what changed from the previous comment, but gave it whirl anyhow. this.selectedColor doesn't log either and my thoughts would be at least I would see undefined at that point if the selectColor() was working. Using (colorPickerChange)="selectColor()"  isn't showing any results sadly.

Comment: Maybe add `console.log(this.selectedColor);` as the first line inside `selectColor()` to see what that is, if anything.

Comment: I think it is the color picker as setting input type to 'color' and stripping out the color picker sends the event. This might be a better way around it - does anyone know any restrictions for type="color" in terms of browser types?

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick - going to bin the ngx-color-picker as it looks like it stops the event being emitted but using this...

```
<ng-container *ngIf="setting">
    <li>
        <input 
        type="color"
        value="selectedColor"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedColor" 
        (change)="selectColor(selectedColor)">
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

solved my problem.

There is one fall back [color types aren't supported for IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color), but as my customers work on macs, this should be fine.